# How can one replace a part of a line with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file which contains many lines(line delimiter is ~). Each line,I have many elements which is seperated by a delimiter '*'. 
What I want to do is ,
 I will be having a line that starts with string TRN in my file. It can have 4(including TRN) or more data points in it. Something like,

```
TRN*1*S521000035*1020494919~
TRN*1*S521000035*1020494919*787989800~
```

I want to replace the fourth data point from this lines to abc123. ie,

```
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123~
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123*787989800~
```

I tried using sed command with regular expression

```
sed -i 's/^TRN\*(.*)\*(.*)\*(.*)$/abc123/g' file.txt
```

But the whole string is getting replaced to abc123.

Is it possible to change only its 4th datapoint using sed command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r -i 's/^((\w+\*){3})\w*(.*)/\1abc123\3/g' file.txt
```

Output:

```
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123~
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123*787989800~
```

Comment: Worked . Thank you very much!

Comment: In the above case i wanted to replace the fourth data point, only if the first data point is TRN. So I tweaked your command as  `sed -r -i 's/^(TRN\*)((\w+\*){2})\w*(.*)/\1\2abc123\4/g' `

Answer (score 2):

**sed** is your friend.

Give a try to this tested version:

```
$ sed "s/^\(TRN[*][^*][^*]*[*][^*][^*]*[*]\)[^*][^*]*\(.*~\)/\1abc123\2/" afile.txt
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123~
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123*787989800~
```

You might want to read the man pages to have more details on **regexp** and **sed**

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^*~]\+/abc123/4' file
```

Replace the fourth occurrence of something which is does not contain a `~` or a `*` with `abc123`.

Answer (score 0):

AWK should do the trick in a pretty concise and readable way. FS changes the field separator so that you can identify where you want it to break inside of a line.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="*|~" }{ sub($4, "abc123"); print $0}' file.txt

TRN*1*S521000035*abc123~
TRN*1*S521000035*abc123*787989800~
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$4 = "abc123"`? Doing a sub instead is a bit strange.

Comment: Because when I did that it removed the "*" from between the fields and the "~" from the end of the first line. Not sure why it did that, but sub solved that problem.

Comment: Because you did not set the output field separator OFS.

Comment: Also using sub means that if $4 occurs earlier in the line then it will remove the earliest string.

Comment: OP said he wanted to replace the fourth data point. How would $4 (the fourth field) occur earlier or later than when the fourth field occurs?

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with **sed** it is much easier to achieve the desired effect with **awk**.  The program **awk** is especially useful to analyse and transform tabular-structured data, as in your case:

```
awk -F'*' -v OFS='*' '{$4 = "abc123"; print}'
```

This reads:

```
awk         Run the program awk
 -F'*'      Use the * as a field delimiter on input
 -v OFS='*' Use the * as a field delimiter on output
 '{         On each record …
   $4 = "abc123";
            … set the 4th field to "abc123"
   print
            … and print the curent record
  }'
```

It is also easy to expand on that example to selectively replace the 4-th field, depending on the value of the other fields.

Comment: Your `awk` command is removing the `~` at the end of line 1 in the example and that is not wanted behavior.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="~\n";FS=OFS="*"}$4="abc123"'`

Comment: @123, Your comment `awk` command introduces a unwanted newline after each existing line and a garbage last line of `***abc123~`.

Comment: @user3439894 Yeah it definitely doesn't introduce any new newlines as the RS and ORS are the same. It will replace blank lines with `***abc123~` though as it adds $4 to every line. The `unwanted newline` is because you haven't used the `~` line delimiter specified by OP.

Comment: @123, Have a look at [this screen shot](http://imgur.com/JL1Wxpd) to see what I'm seeing.  The `~` is at the end of the line as I copied and pasted the example from the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 What does cat -A show on the file, also what version of awk are you using ?

Comment: Mhh, maybe it's time for you guys to switch to a chat room?